# How to move the div to the bottom of the parent div?

Tags: css

How to align the bottom of the red div with class `test` with the bottom the right div?

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lujdru9/

html

```
<div>
    <div class="box">
        <div>sad
            <br/>sad
            <br/>sad
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="test">sad
            <br/>sad
            <br/>sad
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>sad
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.test {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

General I don't suggest it but for your situation you can go with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to child with class `.test` alongside with `position: relative` to parent(I add a class to parent `.cont`).

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.test {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;/*add position absolute*/
  bottom: 0;/*add bottom 0*/
}
.cont {
  position: relative;/*add position relative to parent element*/
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="box">
    <div>sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="test">sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.box {
  background: #c0ffee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.test {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">
    <div>sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="test">sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>sad
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>sad
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```